# Error al pedir datos por consola

Tags: c, printf

He hecho una secuencia para pedir datos por consola (atributos de un struct Usuario), de modo que se vaya pidiendo cada atributo y pasando al siguiente una vez el usuario ingrese el dato y le de al enter, sin embargo, las dos primeras peticiones me salen en la misma línea y no logro ver el error.

```
void registroUsuario() {

    Usuario u;

    printf("\n\n------Resgistro de un nuevo usuario------\n");
    printf("Nombre de usuario:");
    fflush(stdout);
    char str[11];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    sscanf(str, "%s", str);
    u.nombreUsuario = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str)+1));
    strcpy(u.nombreUsuario, str);

    printf("Nombre:");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str), stdin);
    sscanf(str2, "%s", str);
    u.nombre = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str)+1));
    strcpy(u.nombre, str);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);` ya lee un string. No veo el motivo por el que usas: `sscanf(str, "%s", str);`. Ademas de que leer y escribir al mismo string con `sscanf` [es bastante peligroso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582185/does-sscanf-support-recursive-buffer#answer-13582614). Pasando de eso, que tal si nos compartes una cantidad de codigo minima para que podamos reproducir el problema, con lo que nos das no puedo estar seguro de el problema.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario mas código para entender lo que puede estar ocurriendo, lo único la estructura Usuario, pero creo que es evidente que tiene esos 2 atributos.

Comment: Si hace falta mas código. Copie tu código, definí `Usuario` con los 2 atributos, cambie `str2` por `str` para que compilara, y no me salió como a ti. A mi me salieron individualmente, y si no puedo reproducir el problema no te puedo ayudar. Se necesita mas codigo para cononcer el motivo, por ejemplo, puede ser que el `stdio` este sucio por que hayas leido antes con `scanf` y se salte el `fgets`. Te recomiendo que si quieres que te ayuden, traigas un [ejemplo minimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), y que te asegures de que si reproduce el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le hice unos arreglos, por lo que deberia ir bien cuando la implementes en tu codigo, doy por hecho, de que lo que quieres es guardar en `char str[11];` una palabra ingresado desde teclado usando la funcion `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);` por lo tanto usar sscanf a continuacion esta de mas, ya que los datos ya son capturados por fgets

```
void registroUsuario(){
    char str[11];
    Usuario u;

    printf("\n\n------Resgistro de un nuevo usuario------\n\n");
    
    printf("Nombre de usuario: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    u.nombreUsuario = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str)+1));
    strcpy(u.nombreUsuario, str);
    
    printf("Nombre: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    u.nombre = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str)+1));
    strcpy(u.nombre, str);
}
```

Comment: Los datos ya son capturados con fgets, pero se incluye el \n del final, con lo cual formateandolo con sscanf  de string a string se quita el \n, de todas formas creo que ese no es el problema de que me salgan los dos printf a la vez, pero gracias por la ayuda